# Probability that Professor sends k correct addresses

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A Professor prepares n letters and puts them in envelopes and closes them. Then realizes he has to write addresses, now he randomly writes addresses in the closed envelopes. What is the probability that he sends exactly k letters with correct addresses?

Attempt: Fix the k correct letters. We can choose them in $ n\choose k$ ways. Total number of combination is n!. Could I say answer is $\frac {n\choose k} {n!}$.

I am just getting started with probability, please post answers considering this.

Comment: Are you to find the probability that *exactly* $k$ addresses are correct, or the probability that *at least* $k$ are correct? The two are quite different, and the latter is much easier to calculat than the former. (What you have isn’t right for either, however.)

Comment: exactly k addresses are correct. I have edited that now

Comment: After choosing the $k$ envelopes for correct addresses, you still need to ensure that the other $n-k$ are all wrong. This is derangement on $n-k$ symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose which $k$ envelopes will be correctly addressed. That leaves $n-k$ envelopes, each of which *must* be incorrectly addressed. Thus, we need to know $d_{n-k}$, the number of ways to put an incorrect address on each of $n-k$ envelopes; the total number of ways to get exactly $k$ correctly addressed envelopes will then be $\binom{n}kd_{n-k}$, and the probability will be

$$\frac{\binom{n}kd_{n-k}}{n!}\;.$$

The number $d_\ell$ of ways of putting the wrong address on every one of $\ell$ envelopes is the number of [*derangements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $\ell$ things. As you can find at the link, it’s known that

$$d_\ell=\ell!\sum_{i=0}^\ell\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\;,$$

so the probability can be written

$$\frac{\binom{n}kd_{n-k}}{n!}=\frac{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(n-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}{n!}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\;.\tag{1}$$

As an example, suppose that $n=5$ and $k=3$. There are $\binom53=10$ ways to choose the $3$ envelopes that are to be correctly addressed, and there’s clearly just one way to put wrong addresses on the remaining $2$ envelopes, so the desired probability is

$$\frac{10\cdot1}{5!}=\frac1{12}\;.$$

Formula $(1)$ gives the result

$$\frac1{3!}\sum_{i=0}^2\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\frac16\left(\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}\right)=\frac16\left(1-1+\frac12\right)=\frac1{12}\;,$$

as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to fix $k$ points in a permutation of $n$ elements is (in your case, correctly assign $k$ addresses out of $n$ random choices) $$D_{n,k}=\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$$

See [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) (also known as partial derangements).